# Библиотеки синтаксического разбора

Tags: java, синтаксический-анализ, поиск-библиотек

Подскажите, пожалуйста, библиотеки синтаксического разбора предложений русского языка на Java. Могу ли я использовать синтаксический анализатор XML для разбора предложений на естественном языке?

Comment: Можете привести пример входных и ожидаемых выходных данных? Пока нашел AbiWord Link Grammar (https://github.com/opencog/link-grammar), там есть русский язык

Comment: Вы можете использовать любой синтаксический анализатор для разбора предложений... Всё зависит от того, о каком естественном языке идёт речь, они бывают **очень** разные. Всегда можно придумать подходящий для данного анализатора.

Comment: @vp_art, пытаюсь делать парсинг именно русского языка. Как бы это повнятнее сказать. Я не стою у подножия вавилонской башни, я собираю её осколки. Первая сложность с которой я встретился это - "разбор предложений на русском языке не зависит от порядка слов в предложении."